# Bulk Insert on SQL Server timeouts for 62,00,000 records when executed from PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am executing following command in my PowerShell script.

```
$SqlQuery = "BULK INSERT $tableName FROM '$fileContainingFolderPath' WITH (BATCHSIZE = 80000, FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', TABLOCK)"
        
        $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd; Connection Timeout=120"
        $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
        $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
        $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
        $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
        $SqlConnection.Close()
```

It hits a timeout exception; it works sometimes, but does timeout others.

What can I do? It doesn't fail for smaller files.

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s) : "Execution Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code or **errors** when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As for the problem, if you're inserting 62 million **rows** (tables don't have "records") why not increase the timeout? You've specifically stated it to be 2 minutes.

Comment: I did used it 60 , 90 minutes and it works with that timeout as well. My query I think basically is to know if I should rely on increased timeout only? Earlier I used only BATCHSIZE for same set of records, but it started failing all of a sudden for same BATCHSIZE and I started using connection timeout as well. Thanks

Comment: Apart from increasing the timeout, increasing your batch size might also help a bit. 80K is a suspiciously small number.

Comment: @RogerWolf 102400 is the magic number for direct columnstore loading, and makes a good minimum batch size for bulk loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only set the ConnectionTimeout, not the CommandTimeout, which defaults to 30sec.

So set the [CommandTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) and don't use a DataAdapter, since this query doesn't return results:

```
    $SqlQuery = "BULK INSERT $tableName FROM '$fileContainingFolderPath' WITH (BATCHSIZE = 102400, FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', TABLOCK)"
    
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd; Connection Timeout=120"
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
    $SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0
    $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    $SqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: I eventually ended using CommandTimeout with BatchSize & ConnectionTimeout. Without using CommandTimeout it does not works as expected always. Thanks much!